# Where to get hourly weather data for Moscow region

Tags: weather, historical, russia

I'm planning an outdoor event, and want to schedule it on a weekend with warmest nights, and the least probability of precipitation.

My first take was querying forecast.io for hourly historical data. It works, but I quickly ran out of free limit of daily requests. And I also want to extend my query, and find out which is the warmest location within 150 km of Moscow, and that would bring me way beyond the limit.

Is there more straightforward way of getting the data?